# Printing a text tree in python

Tags: python

How would you print a tree in python so it looks like the following:

```
          /\
         /  \
        /    \
       /      \
      /        \
     /          \
    /            \
   /              \
  /                \
 /                  \
```

The height should be changeable.

Comment: @DavidJeon I was about to post my answer, but you deleted the question while I was editing it. Here is the solution.

Comment: Hah, same thing happened to me! Nicely done @francium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def tree(n):
    treeStr = ""
    for i in range(0,n):
        level = " "*(n-i) + "/" + " "*(2*i) + "\\"
        treeStr += level.center(n+1) + "\n"
    print(treeStr)

tree(10);
```

Comment: Cool, so a self-answer question?

Comment: `tree = lambda L: "\n".join("%s/%s\\" % (" " * (L - i), "  " * i) for i in range(L))`