# Python:Christmas Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print a Christmas tree that looks like this:

```
  /\  
 /  \
/    \
```

Here is my code so far:

```py
for count in range (0,20):
    variable1 = count-20
    variable2 = count*2

print('{0:{width1}}{1:{width2}}' .format('/','\\', width1=variable1 , width2=variable2))
```

I am using Python 3.5. And the coding says Sign not allowded in sstring format specifier

Comment: I think you need to use `variable1` etc instead of the hard codes `20`

Comment: what do you mean? do you mean that I shouldn't use width?

Comment: Also `variable1 = count - 20` without the string quotes, etc

Comment: You say `width1=20`, it should be `width1=variable1`

Comment: its says invalid specifier

Comment: Well, it will be a negative sequence, `-20`, `-19`, `-18`, etc. You probably need to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: ok, thanks iw ill try recoding it

Comment: do you still want an answer, maybe using a different approach? It's unclear if you wanted to find the bug or need any working solution

Comment: @DavidJeon you deleted the question yesterday as I was about to submit my answer. I reposted your question and submitted my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236207/printing-a-text-tree-in-python

Comment: Lol sorry I didn't know anyone was editing at that time so I deleted it Xd . I thought if I did a new one I had a better chance of people seeing into it. BUT Great thanks for trying to edit for me.Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works with Python 3.4, I would assume it also works with Python 3.5.

```
    for count in range (20):
        print('{0:>{width1}}{1:>{width2}}' .format('/','\\', width1=20-count , width2=2*count+1))
```

The import part is - as others have mentioned in comments - not to use fixed width for the formatting.

Please notice the neccessary '>' alignment character which is needed for right alignment.

Answer (score 1):

In case you can use a different approach, this one uses a generator and string concatenation

```
n=10
print('\n'.join(' '*(n-i)+'/'+' '*2*i+'\\' for i in range(n)))
```

produces

```
          /\
         /  \
        /    \
       /      \
      /        \
     /          \
    /            \
   /              \
  /                \
 /                  \
```

or, as suggested below by @zvone, why not add some random decorations?

```
print('\n'.join(' '*(n-i)+'/'+''.join(random.choice(' # *') for _ in range(2*i))+'\\' for i in range(n)))
```

produces a much more beautiful result (even partly lit by SO's syntax parser)

```
          /\
         /*#\
        / ###\
       /* #  #\
      /#  ***  \
     /*#  # ##  \
    /   #* * * # \
   /##  **##   *#*\
  /    *  # #  ## #\
 /*# ## *#   * * #* \
```

Merry Christmas!!!

:)

Comment: Why not add some random decorations? `print('\n'.join(' '*(n-i)+'/'+''.join(random.choice('     # *') for _ in range(2*i))+'\\' for i in range(n)))` Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @zvone Hahahaha, gr8! I have added it to my plain and basic answer. Kudos! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import builtins
builtins.unicode = str
print ('                  ',chr(0x2605))
for count in range (20):
    print ('{0:>{width1}}{1:>{width2}}' .format('/','\\', width1 = 20-count , width2 = 2*count+1))
print ('-----------------------------------------'
print ('                 [      ]                ')
print ('                 [      ]                ')
print ('                 [      ]                ')
print ('                 [      ]                ')
print ('                 [      ]                ')
print ('-----------------------------------------')
```

Thank You for the People that helped me FINISH!